# Appropriateness of Security Tools Questions

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of questions of the format "Can't get XYZ working on Kali" or "Error using security tool XYZ when I try to do blah". In most cases, the answers to these questions address an issue with missing dependencies, a product specific solution, or just general UNIX knowledge that is not Kali specific. As a result, I feel like these questions do not really fit in the scope of security as defined in the help center, and just end up cluttering up the front page and not really contributing anything useful. Sometimes, they get closed or moved, but often they are happily answered here.

Sometimes, we might be able to provide more relevant answers having knowledge of the tools, but many of these questions seem more fitting for SuperUser or ServerFault. Are these types of questions really appropriate for SE? .